# Custom email unique validation not working on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, scope, devise

I need to validate email with scope but with devise it is not working. Even after modifying index for email uniqueness it is not allowing user to create on basis of scope.

i have tried adding following line on config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys=[:email, :organization_id]
```

But it doesnot work.

Also i have tried with validation on model:

```
 validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :organization_id
```

But it doesnot work.

Also tried by modifying user migration:

```
def up
  remove_index :users, name: 'index_users_on_email'
  add_index :users, [:email, :organization_id], unique: true
end
```

But it doesnot work as well.

Relation between user model an organization: 
app/models/organization.rb

```
Class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

Here is schema :

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "type"
t.string "full_name"
t.string "email", default: "", null: false
t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
t.string "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string "authentication_token", limit: 30
t.integer "organization_id"
t.string "archive_number"
t.datetime "archived_at"
t.index ["authentication_token"], name: "index_users_on_authentication_token", unique: true
t.index ["email" , "organization_id"], name: "index_users_on_email_and_organization_id", unique: true
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

end

My problem was that: 
I have user with email in organizatin 1 now is have to add another user in organization 2 with same email. While doing this i am getting error

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been
>   taken

I belive that i should be able to add user with same email after adding scope under validation.

Comment: can u add the schema for user relation ??

Comment: Please show what you mean by "not working". ie error message, or what you expected versus what actually happened.

Comment: I have added relation and schema as well. @mahemoff  'not working' mean validation not working as per required.

Comment: I can only guess you mean it saved a record it shouldn't have, but it would help if you're more explicit with an example of what you tried to save and what happened. Otherwise, you're requiring readers to make a lot of assumptions and not necessarily solve your problem.

Comment: please remove the index from the relation using a migration `t.index ["email" , "organization_id"]`

Comment: @mahemoff I have added problem example and error message in above question

Comment: Thanks. "another user in organization" Did you mean "a user in another organization"? Because if it's same organization, the error makes sense.

Comment: Can you please clarify this: Do you want one user to be able to be part of different ogranizations, or you want each organization to have only one unique user? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the email unique validation, you can try this: 
Define following in your model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :organization

  def will_save_change_to_email?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end
end
```

This worked for me.